# Remove square brackets from lists in a column

Tags: python, list, for-loop, nested

I have column with lists in a dataframe. I want to just remove the square brackets:

```
| Fruits                               |
| -------------------------------------|
| [apple, kiwi, pineapple, mango, lime]| 
| [strawberry, cherry, kiwi, orange]   | 
| [...]                                |
```

Desired Output:

```
| Fruits                             |
| -----------------------------------|
| apple, kiwi, pineapple, mango, lime| 
| strawberry, cherry, kiwi, orange   | 
| ...                                |
```

I have tried this

```
for fruit in df['Fruits']:
    df['Fruits'] = (','.join(word))
    print(df['Fruits'])
```

The output is not what I want, and how can I append the new list to a new column (of course without the need of square brackets) anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, try this for string storage or list storge:

```
# String object
df_string = pd.DataFrame({'Fruits':['[apple, kiwi, pineapple, mango]',
                                     '[strawberry, cherry, kiwi, orange]']})

df_string['Fruits'].str.replace('\[|\]','', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
0       apple, kiwi, pineapple, mango
1    strawberry, cherry, kiwi, orange
Name: Fruits, dtype: object
```

Or,

```
#List object
df_list = pd.DataFrame({'Fruits':[['apple', 'kiwi', 'pineapple', 'mango'],
                                     ['strawberry', 'cherry', 'kiwi', 'orange']]})

df_list['Fruits'].agg(', '.join)
```

Output:

```
0       apple, kiwi, pineapple, mango
1    strawberry, cherry, kiwi, orange
Name: Fruits, dtype: object
```

Note:  df_list and df_string string representation looks identical.

```
print(df_list)
                               Fruits
0     [apple, kiwi, pineapple, mango]
1  [strawberry, cherry, kiwi, orange]

print(df_string)
                              Fruits
0     [apple, kiwi, pineapple, mango]
1  [strawberry, cherry, kiwi, orange]
```

Comment: Great answer, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to replace the `[]` characters by `empty` characters with the `replace()` function:

```
for fruit in df['Fruits']:
    df['Fruits'] = df['Fruits'].replace("[", "").replace("]", "")
    print(df['Fruits'])
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it still returns square brackets. I guess because the square brackets are not an element in the list?

Comment: @onik-rahman Yes, it could be the reason. Try applying replace in the output string.